# Table Matching With Margin of Error

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, join

I have two tables. Each table is of the form

```
x   y   m   me
5   6   7   .01
12  14  6   INDEF
```

both are .txt files. Table 2 has similar values, but offset by a small difference (under ~.01) that is not constant between values, and can be positive or negative. What constitutes row 2 in table 1 is not necessarily row 2 in table 2. My output should be of the form

```
x1  x2 xdiff  y1   y2    ydiff
5    6   1     5   5.1   .1
```

where x1 is the x-value of the appropriate piece from table 1, x2 is the value from table 2, and xdiff is the difference between the two, continuing in a similar manner for all columns. In the case of either value being INDEF (they will always either be numbers or that) the difference should also read INDEF. Both tables will have the same number of rows, but that could be anywhere from 4 rows to over 2,000 rows. Their columns are always in the same order.

I know how to do a similar thing in topcat, but now I need to do it in C++, Python 3.x, or some other language (though those two are my first choices). I don't have *any* sort of programming experience-what are the commands I should be looking at? I would want to use the X or Y columns to find appropriate data sets to match, since the m column has a very limited range of values.

Comment: I assume you mean "column" in "What constitutes row 2 in table 1 is not necessarily row 2 in table 2." ?

Comment: No, I mean row. Each row corresponds to a star (this is astronomical data) and those stars might not be arranged in the same order in each table. if star A has its data recorded in row 1 on table 1, it might be recorded in row 5 on table 2. The program needs to use the x and y information to find a match in the other table that's close-they won't have the exact same x and y coordinates, there will be some shift involved.

Comment: Most likely sorting your data will put it in an almost-usable form then.

Answer (score 0):

You really *should* think about moving your data to SQL so you don't have to keep reinventing the wheel.

The following code does mostly what you want.

The floating-point stability problems could be *hidden* by using `decimal.Decimal` but you should really think more about them before doing that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def parse(val):
    if val == 'INDEF':
        return float('nan')
    return float(val)

def unparse(val):
    if val != val:
        return 'INDEF'
    return str(val)

def main():
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit('Usage: ./join.py table1.txt table2.txt')
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as af, open(sys.argv[2]) as bf:
        a_keys = next(af).split()
        b_keys = next(bf).split()
        common_keys = sorted(set(a_keys) & set(b_keys))
        print('\t'.join('%s1\t%s2\t%sdiff' % (k, k, k) for k in common_keys))
        for a_line, b_line in zip(af, bf):
            a_bits = {k: parse(v) for (k, v) in zip(a_keys, a_line.split())}
            b_bits = {k: parse(v) for (k, v) in zip(b_keys, b_line.split())}
            print('\t'.join('%s\t%s\t%s' % (unparse(a_bits[k]), unparse(b_bits[k]), unparse(abs(a_bits[k] - b_bits[k]))) for k in common_keys))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```